# Can we fetch random keys for s3 objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I want to fetch a random sample of 100 s3 object keys from millions of objects in a bucket.

Is there any workaround in s3 API with the maxKeys=100 to list the random object keys every time we use the listV2 API?

Comment: No. You have to first fetch them all, and then sample them yourself.

Comment: Instead of listing the objects, you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. Then you could select random objects from that listing.